# Replacing one shapefile attribute with another using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, update, replace

I have two shapefiles from the same area. One is outdated and the other is updated.

Can I automatically or effectively replace the old ones geometry with new one in QGIS?

Changes are not big but definitely not just slivers.

[image: Black borders represent old geometry and it should be updated to the red one.]

Black borders represent old geometry and it should be updated to the red one.

Comment: Are you asking how to replace the geometry, or how to replace attributes?

Comment: If you're keeping the geometry, it probably easier to replace everything else.

Answer (score 3):

a) there is [a dedicated plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/geometry_paster/),
b) the regular [join attributes by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?highlight=join%20attributes%20location#join-attributes-by-location) should do the job, too:

- delete attributes from the layer with correct geometries (`Input layer`)
- pull correct attributes from the layer with flawed geometries (`Join layer`)
  You might need to experiment which geometric criterion (overlaps/contains/...) yields best results.

Comment: Nice! And maybe even create centroids of the original layer, then spatial join the centroid attributes to the new geometries

Comment: To avoid the possible problem of polygon centroids (as points or as the polygon in a join) falling outside some polygon shapes, I would recommend using the SAGA Point on Surface tool to create the points and then spatially join to those.  Use the create point for each part option.